# selecting records using case select in sql server

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, case, inner-join, exists

```
DECLARE @Test bit= NULL
SELECT  CASE WHEN @Test = NULL THEN 
    (SELECT * FROM Sales WHERE A =1)
    ELSE
    (SELECT * FROM Sales WHERE A =2)
END
```

My Query is NOT exactly this simple but on these lines. I have 7 parameters for a procedure. In the actual stored proc,first select LEFT joins 3 other tables(A,B,C). The second select LEFT joins on 2(A,B) tables of the previous and inner join on Sales itself(A,B,Sales). I tried using union but the first select gets rows which I should NOT see. The second select brings the correct ones. So i thought may be I can do a case select. But I end up with this error

"Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS."

Have any ideas how to proceed? Am I doing something completely wrong? If you need more info, please ask. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps just put it all in the `WHERE`?

```
SELECT * 
FROM Sales 
WHERE (@Test IS NULL AND A = 1)
  OR  (@Test IS NOT NULL AND A = 2)
```

Update: Reading your question again it sounds like you've got different `FROM` situations, in which case use `IF`:

```
IF (@Test IS NULL)
  BEGIN
      SELECT * FROM Sales WHERE A = 1
  END
ELSE 
  BEGIN
      SELECT * FROM Sales WHERE A = 2 
  END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply your case statement in the where clause instead (aslo use `IS NULL` instead of `=`):

```
DECLARE @Test bit
set @TEST = NULL

    SELECT * FROM Sales 
    WHERE A = 
            CASE 
                WHEN @Test IS NULL THEN 1 
                ELSE 2 
            END
```